# Python Web Scraping - After Authentication - Traverse - Download from URL with no Extension

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

In Chrome, I will Log In to a website.
I will then inspect the site, go to Network and clear out existing.
I will then click on a link and snag the header which stores the cookie.

In Python, I then store the header in a dictionary and use that for the rest of the code.

```
    def site_session(url, header_dict):
        session = requests.Session()
        t = session.get(url, headers=header_dict)
        return soup(t.text, 'html.parser')

    site = site_session('https://website.com', headers)
    # Scrape the Site as usual until I reach a file I can't download..
```

This a video file but has no extension.
"https://website.sub.com/download"

Clicking on this link will open up the save dialog and I can save it. But not in Python..
Examining the Network, it appears it redirects to another url in which I was able to scrape.
"https://website.sub.com/download/file.mp4?jibberish-jibberish-jibberish

Trying to shorten it to just "https://website.sub.com/download/file.mp4" does not open.

```
with open(shortened_url, 'wb') as file:
    response = requests.get(shorened_url)
    file.write(response.content)
```

I've tried both the full url and shortened url and receive:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument.

Any help with this would be awesome!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the full url with the query and include the headers.

```
# Read the Header of the first URL to get the file URL
fake_url = requests.head(url, allow_redirects=True, headers=headers)

# Get the real file URL
real_url = requests.get(fake_url.url, headers=headers)

# strip out the name from the url here since it's a loop

# Open a file on pc and write the contents of the real_url
with open(stripped_name, 'wb') as file:
    file.write(real_url.content)
```